# ninject .net 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, ninject

Can you use Ninject 2.0 with VS2010 RC1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if it is compiled for .NET 3.5, the assembly should be able to run in .NET 4. Here's a nice [picture](http://www.vistadb.net/blog/post/2009/12/03/How-Dot-Net-4-Side-by-Side-will-impact-API-writers.aspx).

Comment: Well it does so only when project's target framework is set to .NET 4.0. Without this I get error with message: The referenced assembly "Ninject" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.

Comment: It seems that you are using a version of Ninject that is compiled against .NET 4 in a project targeting .NET 3.5. This is not possible. Download a version of Ninject which is compiled against .NET 3.5.

Comment: The System.Web issue is that he is using the client profile which doesn't have the dll available. Ninject by default compiles against System.Web.dll. You can compile it with a NO_WEB option if you want.

Answer (score 13):

I had similar issue... try targetting the full .NET 4 Framework, not the Client Profile.

From my understanding System.Web is in .NET 4, but not the .NET 4 Client Profile.  So for your assemblies, in which you are taking advantage of full Ninject compiled against 3.5 sp1, you will need to ensure they are not targeting the .NET 4 Client Profile but the full .NET 4 profile in order for the dependency on System.Web to be satisfied.